# Где скачать minGW или Cygwin offline installer?

Tags: mingw, cygwin

Если вы думали что я не могу нагуглить сайты этих компиляторов, то ошиблись. Проблема в том что инталляторы весят 500кб и по сути грузят все остальное из инета, а мне надо скачать и принести другу, у которого нету доступа к инету, к сожалению.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё дело в том, что cygwin может устанавливаться не только из сети, но и из директории, которую вы предварительно выкачали

Попробуйте следовать [этой инструкции](http://www.technixupdate.com/download-cygwin-full-setup-offline-installer/)

Есть ещё один способ: сделать такую упаковку самому, а именно:

1. Скачайте обычный сетап
2. Запустите и выберите Download without Installing
3. Укажите путь куда качать
4. Насттройте прокси если надо
5. Выберите зеркало
6. Выберите нужные пакеты
7. Качаете
8. Запаковываете вашу директорию и заёте другу

UPD: да-да, mingw вы тоже можете выбрать там и всё сработает.

Comment: Все бы ничего, но у меня линукс дома стоит :-D
Пытался найти как скачать все архивы сразу, но видно по одному только качать их =(

Comment: Качайте setup.exe и запускайте его через wine. Он прекрасно работает под вайном и всё качает.

Comment: Скачал последнюю MinGW-get, там нету опции скачать без инсталяции %)

Answer (score 2):

MinGW без MSYS
прекрасно переносится на другой комп без инсталляции.
Зипуете свой, распаковываете у друга в корень C:,
прописываете C:MinGWbin в Path и все... 
gcc ...
strip ...
и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо! Посмотрите здесь например http://code.google.com/p/mingw-offline-install/downloads/list